# Selenium Django Channels error:ERROR: setUpClass

Tags: python, django, selenium

I'm learnig DJango [channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_4.html).It says to install `Chrome` and `Chrome driver` to work with `Silenium`. This is
test case code and everyething from site:

```
from channels.testing import ChannelsLiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


class ChatTests(ChannelsLiveServerTestCase):
    serve_static = True  # emulate StaticLiveServerTestCase

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        try:
            # NOTE: Requires "chromedriver" binary to be installed in $PATH
            cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        except:
            super().tearDownClass()
            raise

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()
        super().tearDownClass()

    def test_when_chat_message_posted_then_seen_by_everyone_in_same_room(self):
        try:
            self._enter_chat_room('room_1')

            self._open_new_window()
            self._enter_chat_room('room_1')

            self._switch_to_window(0)
            self._post_message('hello')
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(lambda _:
                                                'hello' in self._chat_log_value,
                                                'Message was not received by window 1 from window 1')
            self._switch_to_window(1)
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(lambda _:
                                                'hello' in self._chat_log_value,
                                                'Message was not received by window 2 from window 1')
        finally:
            self._close_all_new_windows()

    def test_when_chat_message_posted_then_not_seen_by_anyone_in_different_room(self):
        try:
            self._enter_chat_room('room_1')

            self._open_new_window()
            self._enter_chat_room('room_2')

            self._switch_to_window(0)
            self._post_message('hello')
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(lambda _:
                                                'hello' in self._chat_log_value,
                                                'Message was not received by window 1 from window 1')

            self._switch_to_window(1)
            self._post_message('world')
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(lambda _:
                                                'world' in self._chat_log_value,
                                                'Message was not received by window 2 from window 2')
            self.assertTrue('hello' not in self._chat_log_value,
                            'Message was improperly received by window 2 from window 1')
        finally:
            self._close_all_new_windows()

    # === Utility ===

    def _enter_chat_room(self, room_name):
        self.driver.get(self.live_server_url + '/chat/')
        ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys(room_name + '\n').perform()
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(lambda _:
                                            room_name in self.driver.current_url)

    def _open_new_window(self):
        self.driver.execute_script('window.open("about:blank", "_blank");')
        self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[-1])

    def _close_all_new_windows(self):
        while len(self.driver.window_handles) > 1:
            self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[-1])
            self.driver.execute_script('window.close();')
        if len(self.driver.window_handles) == 1:
            self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[0])

    def _switch_to_window(self, window_index):
        self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[window_index])

    def _post_message(self, message):
        ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys(message + '\n').perform()

    @property
    def _chat_log_value(self):
        return self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#chat-log').get_property('value')
```

Error i'm getting:

```
ERROR: setUpClass (chat.tests.ChatTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\KoronaTime\DjangoPython\DjangoChannels\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "D:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\KoronaTime\DjangoPython\DjangoChannels\siteChannel\chat\tests.py", line 15, in setUpClass
    cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "D:\KoronaTime\DjangoPython\DjangoChannels\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "D:\KoronaTime\DjangoPython\DjangoChannels\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedri
ver/home


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.007s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Cromedriver is in PATH and it works(when i write `chromedriver` in cmd it shows something it has to show). I did not find any solution for an error:`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] unable to find spicified file`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from channels.testing import ChannelsLiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


class ChatTests(ChannelsLiveServerTestCase):
    serve_static = True  # emulate StaticLiveServerTestCase

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

**Note:** `ChromeDriverManager` won't install chromedriver every time while running, it will have it in the cache.